# Finding a program that can find integer solutions for large values of a variable

Tags: list-manipulation, memory, code-review, code-request, diophantine-equations

I've the following code:

```
Table[b = (-12 +Sqrt[3] Sqrt[3 (-4 + r)^2 + 12 a^2 (-2 + r) - 4 a (-5 + r) (-2+ r) +4 a^3 (-2 + r)^2] + 3 r)/(6 (-2 + r)) /. r -> 5;
If[IntegerQ[b], {b, a}, Nothing], {a, 1+10^(11), 10^(12)}]
```

But it gives me the following warning: 'SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]'.

> Is there a way to avoid this warning? Maybe I've to edit my code?

Comment: Well, as it is right now, `a`  iterates through $10^{12}  - (1 + 10^{11})  = 9 \times 10^{11}$ elements.  Do you want to increment a by 1 each time?

Comment: I think your table is too large, it takes 7200000000000 bytes of memory assuming 8 bytes per entry.,  or 7,200 GB RAM if my calculation is right.

Comment: @ThatGravityGuy Yes I would like to do that

Comment: @Nasser Is there a way to work around the big table?

Comment: Re memory, could use `Sow` and `Reap` in a loop instead of `Table`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach suggested by yarchik can be accelerated by two orders of magnitude by performing the computations with machine precision numbers instead of exact numbers and then rounding, and by using `ParallelDo`:

```
SetSharedVariable[s]
s = {}; 
ParallelDo[If[IntegerQ[(1 + a*Round[Sqrt[1./(a*a) + 12. (a + 1)], 10^-10])/6], 
    AppendTo[s, a]], {a, 1, 10^9}] // AbsoluteTiming
s
(* {1795.35, Null} *)
(* 1 *)
```

The computation for `a` as large as `10^9` yields the single answer `a -> 1` in about 30 minutes.  Consequently, the computation for `a` as large as `10^12` should take about 21 days, a long but not impossibly long time.  It seems likely that there are no additional solutions.

Note that there is a tradeoff between increasing the second argument of `Round`, which reduces runtime but also may yield some false positives.  Eliminating the false positives is, of course, straightforward and fast, provided there are not too many.

**Addendum: Solution using Reduce**

The corresponding Diophantine equation is `a^2 + a^3 + b - 3 b^2 == 0`, as can be seen from `Simplify[-(6 b - 1)^2 + 1 + 12 a^2 + 12 a^3]`.  It can be solved by means of `Reduce` for modest maximum values, `amx`, of `a` by

```
amx = 10^6;
SetSystemOptions["ReduceOptions" -> {"ExhaustiveSearchMaxPoints" -> {100, amx}}];
Reduce[{a^2 + a^3 + b - 3 b^2 == 0, amx > a > 0, b > 0}, {a, b}, Integers] 
    // AbsoluteTiming
(* {230.319, a == 1 && b == 1} *)
```

The corresponding run time for the solution by yarchik is 143.7 seconds. For the code given earlier in this answer (but with `ParallelDo` replaced by `Do` for consistency) the run time is 4.00122 seconds.  Of course, the solution using `Reduce` and that by yarchik both can be parallelized, reducing run times proportionately.

Comment: Very nice, but can you please show the solution of the Diophantine equation as it would eliminate the need for numerical search.

Comment: @yarchik  Do you mean solving the Diophantine equation by means of `Reduce`?

Comment: Yes, I would be very much surprised if `Reduce` or any other command can provide a solution because it is not a linear nor quadratic equation. I cannot find the equation in this table https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/009

Comment: @yarchik  Done.  The `Reduce` computation is quite slow, however.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `Table` with `Do`

```
Do[If[IntegerQ[1/6 (1 + Sqrt[1 + 12 a^2 + 12 a^3])], Print[a]], {a, 1 + 10^(11), 10^4 + 10^(11)}]
```

but it is still slow. Try to bring your diophantine equation to some known type.